# How to confirm the drop down loaded completely in Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have three dropdowns on the page

> Country, Region, Province.

When I select Country, based on the country the Region drop-down populated dynamically.

Based on the Region Selection Province will be populated dynamically.

Using Selenium I have selected the Country, but I am not sure how long I need to wait for my drop down region gets populated.

Currently, I am using Thread.sleep...Some time its passes some time it fails because the Region drop-down not completed the loading dynamic values based on the Country selection.

How to wait till the Region drop downloaded completely? I don't want to use the Thread.sleep any other way to come over this.

Comment: please post the code that you already have

Comment: what i would suggest is to click on the body after selecting the dropdown option and make sure your change event is triggered that populates the other dropdown menu options

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep() is always a bad idea in tests.
Use explicit waits with the correct ExpectedCondition.
More info on this can be found [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

If you know what or how many elements are going to be loaded in the dropdowns, you can wait for the DOM to load the correct number of option-elements (part of a select element in HTML)